# Save objects in realm from another thread?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, realm

When i try save object in background, i have exception - "Realm accessed from incorrect thread."
This is initialization for realm - "self.realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm]"

My method for save object in background to realm:

```
- (IBAction)saveProduct:(id)sender {
    Product *product = [Product new];
    [self.productService addProduct:product onSuccess:^{

        NSLog(@"Succes");

    } onFailure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error");

    }];
}
- (void)addProduct:(NSObject *)order onSuccess:(success)success onFailure:(failure)failure
{
    __weak __typeof(self)weakSelf = self;
    dispatch_async(self.queue, ^{
          __strong __typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;

          [strongSelf.dao saveProduct:order];
           dispatch_async(strongSelf.mainQueue, ^{
                success();
           });
     });

}

- (void)saveProduct:(NSObject *)product
{
     ProductModel *model = [self ponsoToModel:product];
     [self.dataBase saveObject:model];
}

- (void)saveObject:(RLMObject *)object
{
     [self.realm beginWriteTransaction];
     [self.realm addObject:object];
     [self.realm commitWriteTransaction];
     [self dataBaseDidSave];
}
```

Comment: Should the code above be in some method?

Comment: @Alistra i update my question, if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> RLMRealm instances are not thread safe and can not be shared across
>   threads or dispatch queues. You must call this method on each thread
>   you want to interact with the realm on. For dispatch queues, this
>   means that you must call it in each block which is dispatched, as a
>   queue is not guaranteed to run on a consistent thread

Comment: Technically, they are "threadsafe" because they are thread-confined and cannot be accessed from two different threads. The thread you see it on will always see a consistent view of the data. But yes, you must open a Realm instance for a given thread, and you can only access RealmObjects, RealmResults and Realms that belong to the given thread where they were initially created.